# Return key value pair from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to return the key, value pair from an array. See screen shot below.

[image]

[image]

In this scenario I have a number of attributes within feature_contributions (TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION, TITANIC.FARE_CONTRIBUTIONS etc). I would like to loop over each attribute and return the key, value pairs e.g (for TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION C
0.02789997960547538, Q 0.023986753511113696 and so on).

My end result should be a list of all the key, value pairs like so:

```
C 0.02789997960547538
Q 0.023986753511113696
S -0.09335021246545774
(7.55, 7.854] -0.0755071986
(7.854, 8.05] -0.0699985221
```

and so on.

Using a forEach loop I can get to the attribute but im struggle to return the key, values within. I have also tried to use a for loop which brings me back the attribute names. Appreciate any help.

```
 record.feature_contributions.forEach((obj) => console.log(obj));

 for (let value of Object.values(record.feature_contributions)) {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text."_

Comment: `Object.entries()`

Comment: Apologies, noted for next time. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
const contributions = record.feature_contributions
    .flatMap((obj) => Object.values(obj))
    .flatMap((contribution) => Object.entries(contribution));
```

As I see from the screenshot you posted, you have a nested structure, which is why the first flatMap is needed. This gives you an array of the contribution objects. From this, you extract the key-value pairs using the `Object.entries()` function.

Tested on this sample data:

```
const record = {
  feature_contributions: [
    {
      "TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION": {
        C: 0.02,
        Q: 0.02,
        S: -0.09
      }
    },
    {
      "TITANIC.FARE_CONTRIBUTION": {
        key1: -0.07,
        key2: -0.06
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the nested structure is what I was strugling with. I then accessed the key using contributions.map((i) => i[0]).